# How to change groupindicator arrow xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

**The problem:** I have changed the groupindicator but the image is stretched horizontally and I cannot fix it

**What I have tried:**
So I tried converting one of the images to a 9 patch image but then xamarin could not find it.
I tried setting the indicatorbounds(0,5) but the arrows then do not appear,
I am so lost, how can  I replace the expanablelistview arrow (groupindicator) with an image and then that image not be stretched but a fixed size I can specify?
I have also played around with the settings selector xml but nothing seems to work!

settings_selector.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
       android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp"
    android:bottom="5dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/uparrow"
        android:state_expanded="true" />

    <item
       android:left="11dp"
    android:right="11dp"
    android:top="12dp"
    android:bottom="12dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/downarrow" />

</selector>
```

Page.axml

```
 `{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ExpandableListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myExpandableListview"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/settings_selector"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

     />}
```

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any problem?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I replace the expanablelistview arrow (groupindicator) with an image and then that image not be stretched but a fixed size I can specify?

The icon image for the groupindicator will always be stretched, usually a 9 patch image which contains only a stretchable pixel at both top and bottom can solve the issue. But if 9 patch image doesn't work for you and you insist to use the image resource, then an easy way to solve the image's stretch problem is to set `android:groupIndicator="@null"` for your `ExpandableListView`.

Then in your layout for list group(Header) of `ExpandableListView`, manually add a `ImageView` for example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:src="@drawable/downicon" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/DataHeader"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
      android:text="DataHeader"
      android:layout_margin="2dp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:paddingStart="50dp"
      android:paddingLeft="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

At last in the code behind subscribe the `GroupClick` event of your `ExpandableListView` for example like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    var listView = FindViewById<ExpandableListView>(Resource.Id.myExpandableListview);
    listView.SetAdapter(new ExpandableDataAdapter(this, Data.SampleData()));
    listView.GroupClick += ListView_GroupClick;
}

private void ListView_GroupClick(object sender, ExpandableListView.GroupClickEventArgs e)
{
    var view = e.ClickedView;
    var indicator = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.indicator);
    if (e.Parent.IsGroupExpanded(e.GroupPosition))
    {
        e.Parent.CollapseGroup(e.GroupPosition);
        indicator.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.downicon);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Parent.ExpandGroup(e.GroupPosition);
        indicator.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.upicon);
    }
}
```

Rendering image of this demo:

[image]